# "Later" vs "later on."

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between the two?

> **Later** the doctors found out that my case was a bit different.
>
> **Later on** the doctors found out that my case was a bit different.

Is one more common than the other?

Comment: you'd only use the first one, I'd say.  "later on" is more of a colloquial expression, used in speech.

Comment: I don't agree with the two answers or with Joe's comment, above (sorry, Joe!). The two constructions have different shades of meaning and are used deliberately in specific situations. Unfortunately that's about all I can offer: at the moment I can't quite put into words what the specific difference is, and can only observe that *later on* is usually used when reference is made to some third, extraneous event.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"later" and "later on" have the same meaning.  Sometimes "later on" is preferred because it has another, smoother rhythmical flow. You can consider "later on" as just a variant for "later".

Answer (score 7):

1. "Later" is definitely more formal than "Later on"
2. According to me the "on" is just a filler to make the sentence smoother.

   For Example- Many times we use "in order to", even though "to" is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

"Later on" is more informal than just plain "later."